# powershell calculated properties for multiple values

Tags: powershell

I am making an Outlook inventory powershell script.. I want to retrieve:

- Account DisplayName
- Account email
- Account type (POP3, IAMP or Exchange)
- Exchange mode (Online, Cached)

Code:

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$namespace.Accounts |
   Select-Object DisplayName, SmtpAddress, UserName, AccountType, ExchangeConnectionMode |
   Sort-Object  -Property SmtpAddress | Format-Table
```

This do the job, but it would really cool if I could use calculated properties to show `AccountType` and `ExchangeConnectionMode` values as custom friendly name, instead of numeric value. For example:

```
AccountType
0 = Exchange
1 = IMAP
2 = POP3
Else = numeric value (real value)

ExchangeConnectionMode
700 = Cached
800 = Online
Else = N/A (or whatever similar text, for non exchange accounts)
```

I already used calculated properties before but only with math calcs and single value (without multiple values). I guess "`foreach`" or "`if`" will be needed... Can't figure it out how :(

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read and follow [Using Calculated Properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) and [Working with Hash Tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx).

Using *Outlook*'s [`OlExchangeConnectionMode` Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/olexchangeconnectionmode-enumeration-outlook) and [OlAccountType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/olaccounttype-enumeration-outlook), the following code snippet should do the job:

```
$AccntTypes = @{ '0' = 'Exchange'; 
                 '1' = 'IMAP';
                 '2' = 'POP3';
                 '3' = 'HTTP'; 
                 '4' = 'EAS';
                 '5' = 'unknown'}
$ExchConnModes = @{'0' = 'Exchange'; 
                   '800' = 'Online';
                   '700' = 'CachedConnectedFull';
                   '600' = 'CachedConnectedDrizzle'; 
  # (incomplete; please update from `OlExchangeConnectionMode` Enumeration)
                    }

Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$namespace.Accounts |
   Select-Object DisplayName, SmtpAddress, UserName, 
    @{Name="AccountType";
      Expression={$AccntTypes[[string]$_.AccountType]}} , 
    @{Name="ExchangeConnectionMode";
      Expression={$ExchConnModes[[string]$_.ExchangeConnectionMode]}} |
   Sort-Object  -Property SmtpAddress | Format-Table
```

Comment: +1. See also `[Enum]::Parse($someEnum, $someValue)`, then you can skip building hashtable-psuedo-enums and just create the enum object from the assembly.

Comment: @jscott I know, you are right however I couldn't involve this native approach not having _Outlook_  installed and therefore relevant assembly nor COM class available for testing…

Answer (score 1):

That is great!

Finally I solved using "switch" and your given ussefull info.

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$namespace.Accounts | Select-Object DisplayName, SmtpAddress, UserName, @{name='AccountType(txt)';expression={
switch ($_.AccountType)
 {
    0 {"Exchange"}
    1 {"IMAP"}
    2 {"POP3"}
    3 {"HTTP"}
    4 {"EAS (Exchange ActiveSync) on mobile devices"}
    5 {"Unknown"}
 }
 }}, @{name='ExchangeConnectionMode(txt)';expression={
switch ($_.ExchangeConnectionMode)
 {
    0 {"N/A"}
    100 {"Offline (Online mode - Work offline selected)"}
    200 {"CachedOffline (Cache mode - Work offline selected)"}
    300 {"Disconnected (Lost Exchange connection)"}
    400 {"CachedDisconnected (Cache mode - Lost Exchange connection)"}
    500 {"CachedConnectedHeaders (Cache mode - Only headers are     downloaded)"}
    600 {"CachedConnectedDrizzle (Cache mode - First headers then full items are downloaded)"}
    700 {"CachedConnectedFull (Cached mode - Full items are downloaded)"}
    800 {"Online"}
 }
 }} | Sort-Object -Property SmtpAddress | Format-Table
```

I will save your code for furter use ;)
Many thanks!!!!